# How to prevent inplace operation of Pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, in-place

I'm trying to write a function to fill missing data in a Pandas Dataframe. The input of the function is a dataframe with missing values and the column name that I would like the missing value to be filled, and it would return a new datafrme with the missing values filled. The problems is that function would also fill the missing values of the input dataframe, which what I'm not intended to do. Please see my codes below:

```
    import pandas as pd
    import numpy as np
    from sklearn.impute import SimpleImputer
    table = pd.DataFrame({'feature1':[3,5,np.nan],'feature2':[4,1,np.nan],'feature3':   [6,7,3]})

    def missingValueHandle(dataframe,feature):
        df = dataframe
        df[feature] = df[feature].fillna(axis = 0, method = 'ffill')
        imp = SimpleImputer(strategy = 'mean')
        df = imp.fit_transform(df)
        return df

    new_dataframe = missingValueHandle(dataframe=table,feature = 'feature1')
    new_dataframe
```

|  | feature1 | feature2 | feature3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 3.0 | 4.0 | 6 |
| 1 | 5.0 | 1.0 | 7 |
| 2 | 5.0 | NaN | 3 |

```
    table
```

|  | feature1 | feature2 | feature3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 3.0 | 4.0 | 6 |
| 1 | 5.0 | 1.0 | 7 |
| 2 | 5.0 | NaN | 3 |

As you can see, my input "table" is changing with the output "new_dataframe", what do I need to do to prevent that from happening?

Comment: Change df = dataframe to df = dataframe.copy()

Comment: @PaoloJ42 thanks, is there a better way to achieve this? or is what you have here a common approach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `assign` method instead of assigning to the passed dataframe.

`.assign` always returns a new dataframe.

```py
def missingValueHandle(dataframe, feature):
  return (
    dataframe
    .assign(**{feature: lambda df: df[feature].ffill()})
    .pipe(SimpleImputer(strategy='mean').fit_transform))
```

In this case this can also be done without a lambda:

```py
def missingValueHandle(dataframe, feature):
  return (
    dataframe
    .assign(**{feature: dataframe[feature].ffill()})
    .pipe(SimpleImputer(strategy='mean').fit_transform))
```

The benefit of the lambda approach is that you can add a row filter in the pipeline before the `assign` and it still works

Comment: Thanks! but this seems to be a complicated and harder to read. I'm wondering if there is a simple fix to my code.

Comment: Making a copy that you modify successively as proposed in a comment a common way. My proposal is the functional approach. You'll have to do one or the other. You can drop the lambda (see update) but to use pandas to it's full power you should get comfortable using the `.assign(field=lambda df: df...)` idiom.